# How could I change my html into a vue component?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to view a tiff file in a web page, I can finish it with test.html, but I need to do it in a vue file, how can I do that?
and I can't know what the exact content in the tiff.js[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
<script src="./jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./src/assets/js/tiff.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">$(function () {
function show(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
    return function (e) {
      var buffer = e.target.result;
      var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: buffer});
      var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
      var width = tiff.width();
      var height = tiff.height();
      if (canvas) {
        $('#output').empty().append(canvas);
      }
    };
  })(file);
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

$('#file').on('change', function (event) {
  show(event.target.files[0]);
});
});</script>
```

that's what the script I used.

Comment: Sry, I have edited it again, here is the script and I want to use them in my vue-cli, but I don't know how to use them

Comment: I think you need to read up on vue and go from there. There is a difference between vue and Jquery.

Comment: I don’t need the Jquery, I just need the tiff.js.

Answer (score 0):

You could install tiff.js as a npm library  `npm i tiff` https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff

And then import tiff to the App.vue for example, other codes go to `mounted(){}`.

Instead of Jquery, you could use event on vue template directly, or use javascript to query the element. Using Jquery with Vue is redundant Ithink